# Невозможно сделать рекурсивный цикл Де Брёйна С#

Tags: c#, python

Перевожу с питона на шарп цикл Де Брейна, на английской версии лежит скрипт, который приведен ниже (слегка его подчистил до неоходимого функционала).

```
def de_bruijn(k, n):
    """
    De Bruijn sequence for alphabet k
    and subsequences of length n.
    """
    alphabet = list(map(str, range(k)))
    a = [0] * k * n
    sequence = []

    def db(t, p):
        if t > n:
            if n % p == 0:
                sequence.extend(a[1:p + 1])
        else:
            a[t] = a[t - p]
            db(t + 1, p)
            for j in range(a[t - p] + 1, k):
                a[t] = j
                db(t + 1, t)
    db(1, 1)
    return "".join(alphabet[i] for i in sequence)

print(de_bruijn(2, 2))
```

Собственно в самом цикле неоднократно происходят вызовы db(x,y), а в шарпе код как будто игнорирует эту инструкцию и спокойно выполняет код дальше. При одинаковых параметрах k n = 2 2, питон выдает необходимые 0011, шарп выдает 0100, поскольку выполняет db единожды, проскакивая рекурсивный вызов, ходя должен минимум трижды выполнится.

```
static int k=2, n=2;
        int[] a = new int[k * n];
        static List<int> sequence = new List<int>();

        void db(int t, int p)
        {
            if (t > p)
            {
                if (n % p==0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i >= p + 1; i++)
                    {
                        sequence.Add(a[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                a[t] = a[t - p];
                db(t + 1, p);
                for (int j = a[t - p] + 1; j < k; j++)
                {
                    a[t] = j;
                    db(t + 1, t);
                }
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db(1, 1);
            string s = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                s += a[i];  
            }
            textBox1.Text = "" + s;
        }
```

Что я делаю не так? Возможно кривой перевод программы, но питон не знаю и не разбирался до сегодняшнего дня, пытался даже вызвать из db другой метод - игнорирует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, вот демонстрация того, почему не надо давать переменным короткие однобуквенные имена. В циклах это нормально, но имена `n`, `t`, `p` - ничего не говорят человеку, который не знаком с алгоритмом + вот можно так и ошибиться как и Вы.
Ошибки:

1. В начале метода `db`, где if, должно быть `t > n`, у вас `t > p`.
2. Неправильно использовали копирование: нужно с первого индекса до `p` включительно: `for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++)`
3. При выводе в питоне используется список `sequence`. У Вас же массив `a`.

Замените:

```
foreach (var item in sequence)
    s += item;
```

Пока набирал ответ, уже указали на опечатку с именами переменных.

Comment: короткие имена вообще зло, разве что для итераторов цикла, типа i, j, k, но не более, даже N, в качестве ограничителя цикла уже плохо, потому как этих N может быть далеко не одна. Правда доходит это обычно очень поздно и очень болезненно, в школе-вузе то было нормально же.

Comment: @rdorn,да, да. Я про i, j, k  и имел в виду. А насчет других буквенных названий, возможно, это считается нормой при использовании в описаниях алгоритмов. Но читать жесть, особенно когда идут t,p,l,d и прочие буквы.

Comment: Да, однобуквенные зло, но сначала я переписал все нормально, когда это не заработало, стал делать под копирку уже, и спустя два часа сидения над кодом я успел запомнить что есть что)
После правки, сказанной вами и выше, плюс ваших правок про foreach, который я не смог победить и цикл, программа стала выдвавать явно что-то лишнее:
0001011
когда при 2. 2 должна была выдать 0011.

Есть догадка, что дело в неправильной интерпретации цикла с range() из питона, пойду копать.

Comment: И вопрос: правильно ли я интерпретировал  sequence.extend(a[1:p + 1]), то есть расширить последовательность на a[1], a[2]...a[p+1]?
Именно туда уходит цикл, и когда он туда попадает второй раз, он прописывает лишние три значения "010", и без них выходная последовательность абсолютно верная!

Comment: Не успеваю отредактировать третий раз подряд:

Мусор начинается как только вызывается цикл for в конце метода, псле этого вызывается db с такими параметрами, которые гадят в последовательность. Но я не могу понять, почему, код теперь 1 в 1 как змеиный.

Comment: @KormakovN, а что с foreach'ом не получилось? У меня нет возможности проверить алгоритм на правильность. Но те правки, которые я сказал, они делают код одинаковым с питоновским.
Интерпретировали сейчас, в комментарии? В коде вы неправильно сделали, в п.2 я указал как правильно: занести в последовательность, начиная элемента индексом 1 до p включительно.

Comment: @KormakovN, C#: https://repl.it/BuSC/1
Python: https://repl.it/BuSL/0
Все работает. Надеюсь, сможете перенести к себе. Если что, пишите

Comment: @nuts119 - ваш код работает, в том числе при переносе в мою программу, спасибо. Но почему ваш работает, а мой срет - загадка)

Comment: @nuts119
С foreach не понимал, как сделать цикл, как-то грамотного объяснения в сети сразу не нашел и решил не зацикливаться, потому что в массив летело все тоже самое, что и в последовательность, поэтому пошел по наименьшему сопротивлению, но теперь вкурил.

Answer (score 3):

методом пристального вглядывания:
питон:

```
if t > n:
```

C# в том же самом месте:

```
if (t > p)
```

Возможно еще есть опечатки по невнимательности.